# VIM Removing duplicate lines

Tags: vim

I have an issue regarding editing strings using VIM, I currently have the following strings:

**The red fox.**

**The red fox.**

**The blue fish.**

**The blue fish.**

Question: how do I remove the duplicates? and lets say that I have a minimum of 500 lines with duplicates

Expected result:

**The red fox.**

**The blue fish.**

Answer (score 28):

If you do not need to preserve the order of the lines you can do:

```
:sort u
```

i.e. sort all lines and remove duplicates.

Comment: So many years using Vim and a specific script to do this... and finally discovering this so simple method... I am destabilized ^^. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to sort lines:

```
:g/^\(.*\)$\n\1/d
```

Explanation:

```
:g/^\(.*\)$\n\1/d
 g/            /d   # Delete the lines matching the regexp
   ^\(.*\)$         # Match a whole line and put it in substitution register 1
           \n\1     # Match substitution register 1 preceded by new line
```

Comment: This only works when the duplicated lines are one below the other. How to do this when there are other lines between the duplicates?

Comment: @iuvbio That regex deletes one line if the one _immediately after_ is the same. If you can afford to sort the results, then go for the [other answer (Peter's)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29418407/222529). If you still can't, then you'll need something more clever (a script) that parses the file and keeps unique entries as it goes through. Surely that can be done in Vim, but a first approximation in Python could look like this: `python -c "uniq = []; [uniq.append(l) for l in open('test_file.txt') if l not in uniq]; print(uniq)"`. Beware the `not in` check is not very efficient.

Comment: Hmmm. Appears to be (destructively) wrong. Did you perhaps mean :g/^\(.*\)\n\1$/d   instead?         Reason: a quick breakdown of that RE reveals that if it matches one line, then another like the first but *without* insisting the second match terminating with the end of the line, both lines are gobbled. Result: lines like "foo\n"foo123\n" will result in the former simply disappearing, leaving just "foo123".

Comment: This is perfect! My use case is I had an un-sortable file with both consecutive duplicates and separated duplicates, and I only wanted to remove the consecutive ones. Thanks a bundle!